# comparison.cloud function in wordcloud gives out wrong data

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm trying to do some Twitter sentiment analysis with R, syuzhet and the comparison.cloud function in wordcloud. The words in the output don't correspond to where they should be.

My matrix (x) looks like this:

```
           positive negative
marketing        11       10
learn            40        4
change            3        4
better            7        5
make             10        6
helping           6        5
```

Here's the code:

```
x <- cbind(c(11,40,3,7,10,6),c(10,4,4,5,6,5))
rownames(x) <- c("marketing","learn","change","better","make","helping")
colnames(x) <- c("positive","negative")

comparison.cloud(x, colors = c("blue", "red"))
```

The expected outcome is that "marketing", "learn", "better", "make" and "helping" would be on the "positive" side in blue and change would be the only one in "negative" in red.

What actually happens is "learn" is blue and all the rest are in red.

[image: Here's the output.]

From what I can figure, comparison.cloud checks if a word has a value in the "negative" column above 0 and if it does, it automatically plots it in the "negative" section, even if the "positive" is a higher number.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(11,40,3,7,10,6),c(10,4,4,5,6,5)))
x$types <- c("marketing","learn","change","better","make","helping")
colnames(x) <- c("positive","negative", "types")
x$all <- x$positive + x$negative
colorVec = ifelse(x$positive > 11, "blue", "red")
x <- x[,c("types", "all")]

library(wordcloud2)
wordcloud2(x, color = colorVec, fontWeight = "bold")
```

[image]

Comment: That works well. I removed the words with equal positive and negative values and set `colorVec = ifelse(x$positive > x$negative, "blue", "red")`.

However, wordcloud2 doesn't quite have all of the functionality of wordcloud and comparison.cloud. I'm ultimately looking to achieve something like [this](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/0*nNzj3ZgjCaSjLtjC.).